# Issue getting menu to swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swipe

I am using jQuery's swipeLeft and it works for the most part except for one thing I cannot figure out. If I put the div that I am trying to swipe off the page, ie: treating this as a mobile menu that I would swipe to display, the function no longer works.

I am using the exact code jQuery has on [their site](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/).

The only thing I changed was

```
  div.box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 3em;
    background: #108040;
    margin-left: 101%;
  }
  div.box.swipeleft {
    background: #7ACEF4;
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
```

Anyone have any ideas why this will not swipe if I take it off the page or how I can get it work off the page?

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6kbkjsg/1/), though it doesn't work on it for some reason. If someone wants to see this live just let me know.

Comment: No, I cannot have the div display on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start your **External Resources** was in wrong order. You should start with **Jquery library** and **Jquery Mobile** after, its must because **Jquery Mobile** relies on the main **Jquery library**.

---

### This is the correct order:

1. [jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css)
2. [jquery-1.10.2.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js)
3. [jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js)

---

And to your question, **look at this example:** [**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/43kjns4d/4/)

(Just remove the border if you need a white page)

---

**Note:** for loader hiding use this line:

```
$.mobile.loading().hide();
```

Comment: The normal form of this worked fine for me this entire time, I must have just inserted the external resources wrong. The issue was how to get this to swipe while it is off the page. That is the whole point of it.

Comment: this is all you added to make this work? `$.mobile.loading().hide();`?

Comment: no, you need to make the event for the new parent div and the function find() the child (".box"). look at my example.